# Deleter more than 50 e-mails in gmail in 2020

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Last time when I selected the e-mails on a page to delete, after selecting 50, gmail offered that it could mark all the e-mails having that label.

Now it does not.

How can I select all that 9000 e-mails now?

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, I went to the oldest 50 e-mails on that label, and then gmail offered to mark all the thousands e-mails after selecting the page's e-mails.